# "The provided client secret keys are expired" when trying to obtain an access token from the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to integrate an Outlook calendar into a system (web application) that I'm building for a small business (React frontend, Django Rest Framework backend), so that users can view all their calendar events on the system, as well as creating and updating them there, without having to go back and forth between Outlook and the system.

I'm not having any problems with the coding itself, but only the retrieval of access tokens so that I can access users' calendars, and once I have that, the actual implementation should be relatively straightforward.

But no matter what I try, I keep getting the error `AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys are expired.`, which is weird, since the client secret key I created is set to never expire.

I followed the docs for both [Get Access on Behalf of a User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) and [Get Access Without a User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), but I have received the same error message in both cases. I'm not completely sure what the difference is, but I assume that the docs for "Get Access on Behalf of a User" is the correct approach I should be taking, because each user's calendar needs to be accessed so that events can be displayed and created. I know for sure that I have provided the correct values for the `client_id` and `client_secret`, because they match exactly to what I have on the app that I have registered on Azure.

First, I tried the following (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service):

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

using Postman, changing the `client_id` and `client_secret` values to match what I have on my app.

I got the error message `AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys are expired.`, so I decided to try the following (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read
&state=12345
```

changing all values where necessary (tenant as `common`, as well changing the `client_id` and `redirect_uri`)

The response from that gave me an access code, which I used in the following:

```
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20mail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh
```

where I again changed the values as necessary, but I still received the same error message as above `AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys are expired.`.